# C# LINQ Lambda query with select, Where, Count and Distinct

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am brand new to linq and i need help with a query. I have 3 columns in a datatable. I need to get a count of unique values from col3, where col1 and Col2 contain certain values. here is the last piece of code i tried, but it is not working. can someone please help me with this?

thanks

```
AD = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(x => x.Field<string>("Col1").Equals("Value1") 
             || x.Field<string>("Col2").Equals("Value2"))
    .Select(s => s.Field<string>("Col3")
    .Distinct().Count());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm missing a closing parenthesis at `.Select(s => s.Field<string>("Col3")`, try this:

```
AD = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(x => x.Field<string>("Col1").Equals("Value1") 
             || x.Field<string>("Col2").Equals("Value2"))
    .Select(s => s.Field<string>("Col3")) // <-- add this
    .Distinct().Count();   // <-- remove this
```

Comment: @user2219930: note that your code compiled but did something different: it selected the number of distinct characters in the string-field `col3` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
var q1  = (from persons in _db.Table<Person>()
            where persons.firstName==fname && persons.lastName==lname group
 persons.age by persons.age ).Count();
```

I 've tested this on some "test" cases using sqlite-net library - and it seems to work.
Although there is already a solution - they are using different styles , so I decided to post it there to